# What is ethical liberalism?

Tags: political-theory, liberalism

I have recently seen a conference organized by an ex-PM which [discussed about the creation of a new political party](http://www.business-review.eu/news/former-pm-ciolos-romania-100-platform-to-transform-into-political-party-154154).

One of the speakers mentioned that the party will be centered around "ethical liberalism", but did not explain what it does actually mean.

Googling for it, I found this [short article](http://www.aei.org/publication/ethical-liberalism/):

> The definition of Lord Acton’s Whiggery is based upon an idea of
>   liberty firmly rooted in responsibility and based upon respect for the
>   law; it is not freedom from the law, but freedom under it. Free men
>   are those who can do what they ought, and not those who do as they
>   wish. It is only by continually exercising this freedom that free
>   societies will remain so. Real liberty has its own responsibilities.

This sounds like a summary than an actual definition.

**Question: What is ethical liberalism?**

Also, it would be interesting to know if this is a core value of any existing political party within an EU country.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Ethical Liberalism

There *is* a philosophy called ethical liberalism. It's also sometimes called "post-Kantian liberalism".  A few differences from classical liberalism:

- Classical liberalism is utilitarian in nature. It's goal is to provide the most happiness (or utility) to the greatest number, while incurring the least disutility (or unhappiness).  Ethical liberalism is focused on social issues, especially justice.
- It assumes people are ethical, rather than rational. Classical liberalism assumes that people naturally seek their own pleasure (or utility). Ethical liberalism does not assume this, but instead assumes that people have some concept of "good" (or virtue) that helps them decide what to do.
- Because of their focus on justice and virtuous behavior, ethical liberalism supports wealth redistribution policies (such as the New Deal in America). Classical liberals oppose these policies for a variety of reasons, most notably because it violates the concepts of property rights and free exchange.

Although we rarely refer to it by name, this view is incredibly common in the United States. In my experience, often times people who label themselves as "liberal" or "progressive" in America often times claim these kinds of views.  Your mileage may vary.

Further reading:

[Shiffrin, 1983](http://heinonline.org/HOL/Page?handle=hein.journals/uclalr30&g_sent=1&casa_token=&collection=journals&id=1125) (UCLA Law Review) contains an excellent discussion of ethical liberalism and contrasts it to classical liberalism.

[Lund, 1996](https://search.proquest.com/docview/215327274?pq-origsite=gscholar) (Political Research Quarterly) delves deeper into two different views of ethical liberalism.

### But

It seems unlikely that a public servant would know about this theory, unless they were specifically trained in some kind of field involving social philosophy.  More likely, they  were trying to invoke a particular kind of idea or feeling in the listener.

A similar phrase from the American experience is "compassionate Conservatism". It isn't intended to be a technical term, just a way to communicate an intangible notion to the audience.

Comment: Although the ex-PM (within a government mostly containing technocrats) happens to be a very decent politician, the concept was mentioned by one of his invited speakers: a female professor who most likely has a background in social philosophy. Indeed, I think they are trying to have a speech that opposes the general feeling that most politicians and institutions are corrupt and that another kind of politics is possible.

Comment: @Alexei I don't see that information in the linked articles. Thanks, that's good background info.

Comment: yes, the article contains little information. I know this detail because I watched the entire conference when the party creation was announced. Unfortunately, there is no transcript.

Answer (score 15):

The link in the OP is to the [American Enterprise Institute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Enterprise_Institute), a conservative thinktank, and frankly the piece is somewhat incoherent. I doubt it has any relevance to what a Romanian politician means by "ethical liberalism".

"Liberal" is a word which doesn't have a firmly agreed-upon definition. It's used in the names of [centrist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberal_Party_of_Canada), [centre-right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venstre_(Denmark)), and even [far-right](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberal_Democratic_Party_of_Russia) political parties.

"Ethical" in this context has even less specific meaning. It's basically there because it sounds nice; after all, no politician is ever going to openly campaign on being *unethical*.

So in summary, "ethical liberalism" means whatever former PM Ciolos wants it to mean.

Comment: I thought it was a real political concept with some clear meaning attached to it. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: "liberal" is used by far-left as well...

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo Do you have an example? I don't know of any socialists, anarchists, communists, etc who would use that label. Center-left maybe (in the US), but far-left doesn't seem correct.

Comment: @tim Only time I have heard it referred to on the left is the US. The US right likes to throw it at the US left and the US left embraces it. Especially now. I also know that in the US they will say things such as "I'm a fiscal conservative, but social liberal" which is another thing entirely.

Comment: Wish I could upvote 10 times. "It's basically there because it sounds nice" seems like an answer to a lot of political expression and especially branding :)

Comment: Another problem here is that an American Conservative and an American Liberal have very little in common with European definitions so it's hard to factor them in the classic left-right political spectrum.  According to Wikipedia, the former has more in common with "Classical Liberalism" (but still champion "traditional [American] values) while the latter has more in common with "Social Democracy" (but still holds strong Capitalist principles).

Comment: @tim almost the whole left scene, for example? feminists, greens, all parties that have 'left' in name?

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo I seriously doubt that all feminists and "greens" are far-left, using any reasonable definition of far-left. And those that are indeed far-left would probably reject the liberal label.

Comment: @tim really? if rejecting religion, being anti-conservative and pro-social is not left, what is then? Actually, do you know any definition of 'left' that would exclude anticonservative socialists?

Comment: This is marked as a theory question, but ignores that "ethical liberalism" is in fact a term from political theory. And "liberalism" does have a fairly solid meaning within political theory.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo I think you are conflating US politics with global politics. Globally liberalism is much more of a rightest idea, because it involves a lack of regulation, e.g. neo liberal politics and the free market economy. Also "rejecting religion, being anti-conservative and pro-social" is not globally far left and may not be globally left at all as far left ideologies are basically anarchism.

Comment: @Jake I think left and right are more fluffy concepts then liberalism as they more reflect tribal affiliation of time and place than any particular phylosophy. Liberalism OTOH describes a particular tradition of political thought descendant of which are on all sides of left-right spectrum though traditionally it promoted both free market and social freedoms. Conservatives might argue that as it seeks to 'destroy traditional values' it is leftist idea as well.

Comment: @MaciejPiechotka I don't disagree and I guess I over simplified, but I see it sort of like "liberal" -> "loves liberty" -> "individual freedoms" -> "less state interference" -> "right wing"

Comment: This whole conversation about what "liberal" means is very interesting. The word as originally applied to the political/social meant being more open to or in favor of political change from the status quo. But then it became a label for specific strains of ideological/political/social positions that were, at the time, "liberal" in that original sense. Then the times changed and some of those ideas became more mainstream while retaining the label. Plus definition drift in general as people (re/mis)interpreted the word. And some symptoms of all of the above are exhibited here.